# How to trigger a websockets message from outside the routing() block in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

If I have an Kotlin application that wants to trigger outgoing Websocket messages in Ktor, I usually do this from within the relevant routing block. If I have a process *outside* of the routing block that wants to send a Websocket message, how can I trigger that?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a Ktor Websocket server and you want to send messages through an outgoing channel of a session outside the route's block?

Comment: I have a Ktor websocket server. I currently respond to incoming requests via logic in the routing block. I want to send outbound messages triggered by events outside the routing block too, and this is what I am unsure about.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the session provided by the web socket connection and then you can send messages in that session:

```
var session: WebSocketSession? = null

try {
    client.ws {
        session = this
    }
} finally {
    // clear the session both when the socket is closed normally 
    // and when an error occurs, because it is no longer valid
    session = null
}
// other coroutine
session?.send(/*...*/)
```

Comment: I thought `client.ws { ... }` would close the session automatically at the end of the block. Are you sure this works? Last time I checked I had to use `val session = client.webSocketSession { .. }` which does return the session and lets you manage its lifecycle: https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow/blob/main/krossbow-websocket-ktor/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/hildan/krossbow/websocket/ktor/KtorWebSocketClient.kt#L19

Comment: @Joffrey yes, it's a suspend function and it's not gonna return as far as you're connecting/connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coroutines' channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#closing-and-iteration-over-channels) to send a Websocket session and receive it in a different place:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel

suspend fun main() {
    val sessions = Channel<WebSocketSession>()
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, 5555, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(WebSockets) {}
        routing {
            webSocket("/socket") {
                sessions.send(this)
            }
        }
    }

    server.start()

    for (session in sessions) {
        session.outgoing.send(Frame.Text("From outside of the routing"))
    }
}
```